# Getting 415 Unsupported Media Type in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

Method in controller

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/reactEmployee", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
    public String addEmployeereact(@RequestBody EmployeeEntity employeeEntity)
    {
        employeeManager.addEmployee(employeeEntity);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

Json input from Postman
[Json input and 415 error in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZ0bL.png)

Comment: What value do you provide for header `content-type` in Postman? Edit: also, how does `EmployeeEntity` looks like? It might be the problem that method expects single entity, yet you provide a list. Please edit the question to provide `EmployeeEntity` class. Thank you.

Comment: EmployeeEntity looks like db's table structure It is a model for this project..It contains getter and setter for all column fields..Thank you !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at github link I found that `jackson` needs to be specified in `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Hi bro!! It gives some random values such as "com.adkdinesh.template.entity.EmployeeEntity@7a6a7007"  @7a6a7007=?

Comment: I need to develop rest api ... Json is not accept by spring in my case.. but i donno what is the problem

Comment: its calling ```toString()``` method of entity. what is not working now?

Comment: It return null value to each field bro!. it makes content violation error for hibernate

Comment: so that means its not related to 415 now. Please check your request body and fields if they are matching

Comment: You can push your sample to github I can take a look

Comment: https://github.com/Dineshkumargits/SpringHibernateTemplate--this is my sample code please have a look.. Thank you bro!!

Comment: Please provide your contact details bro!! Thank You

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?